# Aerospike: LDT Sub-Record Create Error Note:-ldt-enabled is true

Tags: aerospike

Using Aerospike 3.7.3 and Large stack. Please help.

I am facing following error.

> Mar 19 2016 05:00:17 GMT: WARNING (ldt): (ldt_aerospike.c::507) crec_create: LDT Sub-Record Create Error [rv=-1]... Fail

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Aerospike) The Large Stack data type has been deprecated. Also, the Large Data Types in general are not at the same level of maturity as the rest of the platform and are not recommended for production use. There are some edge cases situations were Large Data types would end up corrupted. I would recommend running a scan (backup would do) which should print details on the bad LDTs that can then be removed from the system (and potentially re-inserted). I would highly recommend finding alternate data modeling without LDTs.

Comment: @Maher, Thanks for your reply. I am planning to migrate all of my LSTACK data to LLIST. But what surprised me is, LDT is not for production use. I have not read this in any of Aerospike documentations. My usecase is, push JSON (500bytes) to LLIST against a user whenever he does an activity. On reading back the record against the user, I will get all his activities If I go for regular put for every activity and having secondary index on user, I will definitely overflow RAM sooner. Please suggest if I can proceed with LLIST, or what could be the right Data model. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I would recommend not using an LLIST, and rather use a list or map. We are adding new APIs for manipulating those data types, so stay tuned in the coming weeks. For having records going above the maximum 1MB write block size, I would recommend breaking those up at the application level, using for example a 'control bin' to indicate potential overflow into other records. Such method would definitely not increase the RAM usage compared to what the Large Data Types would use.